# How do I read a local text file?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to read a local text file automatically whenever my webpage is opened on my computer. How can I do this? I used the following code from one of solutions answered on this site and it says "Access is denied".

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var fileDisplayArea = document.getElementById('fileText');  //to show output
function readTextFile(file)
{
    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rawFile.open("GET", file, false);
    rawFile.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if(rawFile.readyState === 4)
        {
            if(rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0)
            {
                var allText = rawFile.responseText;
                fileDisplayArea.innerText = allText 
            }
        }
    }
    rawFile.send(null);
}

readTextFile("file:///Location/fileToBeRead.txt");
</script>
```

Is there any other solution to this problem?

Comment: Run it from `localhost`... Do not use `file://` path..

Comment: It worked on my computer. But, actually, I wanna use it on my Android and plot the read data on browser.  The text file has some readings of sensor.

Comment: What if you used a file input like here: http://oss.sheetjs.com/js-xlsx/ ?

Comment: You could do it if you are running a server on your computer. You would need to have a server side script like PHP to read the file and output it. Something like `readfile('path/to/file.txt')` and then you would change your code to `readTextFile("http://localhost/path/to/script.php");`

Comment: @Max Sorin, That is not automated, here ,we have to select the file.

Comment: @AbdulAtique Then what's the question again? You *can not* read files on the client.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot read file off a persons local machine.

You can only read files from the same domain that your site is running on (or if using jsonp to get past XSS rules)

Answer (score 0):

You should not be reading files on a client machine. Its a security issue and hence not allowed (access denied). 
If you want to store data on client machine use cookies rather or as correctly pointed out use a html session or local storage.

Answer (score 0):

For security, natively there's no method to read system files (from URL... `file:///...`).

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use the [Local Storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) feature of HTML5 to do this.